# I tried to solve it by using range, but I could not figure it out all

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

I have a grid of words such as

```
ghgkka

jyjukb

rtbuyd

rjbkuf
```

I want to make the list with vertical letters together such as

```
vertical = ['gjrr', 'hytb', 'gjbb', 'kuuk', 'kkyu', 'abdf']
```

Another list diagonally such as

```
diagonal = ['gybk', 'hjuu' , 'guyf']
```

I did it like

for i in range(len(grid)):

```
elem = grid[row][0]

vertical.append(elem)
```

but it is just printing first column of letters

Comment: `I tried to solve it by using range`: Show us what you tried.

Comment: first I made a list of all the lines of the grid and then used a for loop

Comment: share the information in the question section

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code there.

Comment: btw, vertical should be `['gjrr', 'hytj', 'gjbb', 'kuuk', 'kkyu', 'abdf']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier with numpy. I am not using it as I don't know if you have exposure to it.

Here's using simple loops (list comprehension) to get this done.

```
word_string = '''ghgkka
jyjukb
rtbuyd
rjbkuf'''

word_list = [list(wd) for wd in word_string.split('\n')] #store the data into a list of list

cols = min(len(wd) for wd in word_list) #find how many columns we have
rows = len(word_list) #find how many rows we have

#iterate thru each columns one at a time
#for each column, iterate thru the rows to create a string. Thats your vertical strings

word_vertical = [''.join(word_list[j][i] for j in range(rows)) for i in range(cols)] 


#To do this diagonally, it has to be the difference between the # of rows & cols + 1
# if we hav 6 cols and 2 rows, we will iterate thru it 5 times abs(6-2) = 4 + 1 = 5
# Length of string will be min of 6 and 2. thats 2

# if we have 6 cols and 4 rows, we will iterate thru it 3 times abs(6-4) = 2 + 1 = 3
# Length of string will be min of 6 and 4. thats 4

# if we have 2 cols and 6 rows, we will iterate thru it 5 times abs(2-6) = 4 + 1
# Length of string will be min of 6 and 2. thats 2

diag = abs(cols-rows) + 1 
slen = min(rows,cols)

# iterate thru the # of times possible (diagonal count)
# extract string based on max string length we can get (slen)

word_diagonal = [''.join(word_list[i][j+i] for i in range(slen)) for j in range(diag)]

print (word_vertical)
print (word_diagonal)
```

The output of this will be:

```
['gjrr', 'hytj', 'gjbb', 'kuuk', 'kkyu', 'abdf']
['gybk', 'hjuu', 'guyf']
```

Comment: I assume you want to extract the vertical only for the minimum length of one of the strings in the list. If you want to create a vertical string ignoring the row with fewer strings, then code has to be modified. For example, if we have 3 rows with strings `['abcdef','wxyz',',pqrst']`, then we have 6,4, 5 as string lengths. The above code will create 4 strings `['awp','bxq','cyr','dzs']`. It will ignore the `ef` and `t` from the first and third row